# embed GWT component TWICE and more in HTML page

Tags: gwt

I need to embed my GWT component which is a text area which do some functionalities in the key up and key down events twice and more on the same HTML page, in fact when i try to embed it in two different DIVs it appears only one time.
can any one help figure that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A widget can only have one parent in the DOM. The widget will be contained by the last parent to which it is added. If you need to have a widget type appear more than once on the page you need to create more than one instance of the widget.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but as i mentioned i use the events keyup and key down in the text area so i have to implement those events in each instance of the text area!!!....i feel it is donkey work to do such stuff:):D

Comment: Wrap the text area with a Composite to create your own widget type that includes the keyup and keydown event handlers.

Comment: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html